# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, runtime-error

This code works fine on android version below 9 but crashes on 9 and ABOVE:
[image: THE IMAGE OF ERRORS I GOT]

```java
public class Utils_String {

    public static String prepareContacts(Context ctx,String number) {
        if (number.isEmpty())
            return "";
        
        String preparednumbers=number.trim();
        preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace(" ","");
        preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace("(","");
        preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace(")","");
        if(preparednumbers.contains("+")) {
            preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace(preparednumbers.substring(0,3),""); //to remove country code
        }
        preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace("-","");
        return preparednumbers;
    }

}
```

The code where I call `utils_Strings`:

```java
recyclerAdapter.setListener(new Adapter_incoming.itemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, int position) {
        if(mensu){
            Contacts_data contacts1= (Contacts_data) searchPeople.get(position);
            String records= GetContact.getRecordsList(v.getContext(),recordings,"IN",contacts1);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>18){
                GetContact.openMaterialSheetDialog(getLayoutInflater(),position,records, Utils_String.prepareContacts(ctx,contacts1.getNumber()));
            }else{
                GetContact.showDialog(v.getContext(),records,contacts1);
            }
        }else {
            Contacts_data contacts= (Contacts_data) realrecordingcontacts.get(position);
            String records= GetContact.getRecordsList(v.getContext(),recordings,"IN",contacts);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>18){
                GetContact.openMaterialSheetDialog(getLayoutInflater(),position,records, Utils_String.prepareContacts(ctx,contacts.getNumber()));
            }else{
                GetContact.showDialog(v.getContext(),records,contacts);
            }
        }
        GetContact.setItemrefresh(new GetContact.refresh() {
            @Override
            public void refreshList(boolean var) {
                if(var)
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you calling that method?  What are you using for the parameters?

Comment: Where exactly you are calling Utils_String ? and did you check for 
1. NULL value 2. !TextUtils.isEmpty(number)) 3. check for "" or 'null' (if it's from cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the number is null or not, after that you can check if the value is empty or not.

As @Jon Skeet commmented, the best way approached this is, add new condition using OR for null

```
public static String prepareContacts(Context ctx, String number){
   if(number == null || number.isEmpty()){
      return "";
   }else{
      String preparednumbers=number.trim();
      preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace(" ","");
      preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace("(","");
      preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace(")","");
      if(preparednumbers.contains("+")){
            preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace(preparednumbers.substring(0,3),""); //to remove country code
      }
      preparednumbers=preparednumbers.replace("-","");
      return preparednumbers;
   }
}
```

Comment: This won't currently compile - it doesn't return anything if `number` *is* null. Rather than indent most of the body further, I'd rewrite it as `if (number == null || number.isEmpty()) { return ""; } and then the rest of it can be all at the "top level" of the method, which will make it easier to read.

Comment: @JonSkeet should I update my answer, and credit to you ?

Comment: Feel free to update your answer with my suggestion if you agree with it - no credit necessary.